# Is there a female version of ikemen?

Tags: words, slang, word-requests

Ikemen means something like cool man, is there something similar for women?

Comment: Doesn't it mean 'good-looking man'?

Comment: Judging from the answers below I think so, but I read it to be a cool man.

Comment: To get the obvious facetious answer out of the way: *ikewomen*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not believe there would be a word that everyone could agree upon as the word 「イケメン」 itself is pretty new.

If you are looking for a new word, we have 「イケジョ」 even though it is not wide-spread yet.

More common (and traditional) words include: [美人]{びじん}、[美女]{びじょ}、べっぴん、べっぴんさん, etc.  All are safe choices.

「かわいこちゃん」(with only one い) was a very common word when I was growing up, but it feels kinda retro now.

You could say (and we do often say) 「きれいな人」 though it is not one word.

Answer (score 4):

Because it just means "good looking / handsome man" the female version will be 美人 (bijin) meaning "pretty women".

Maybe your also interested into the fairly newly created words デキ女 (dekijo) and デキ男 (dekidan) for a more characterwise coolness in the sense of someone who is successful f.e. in job.

Comment: There also is モテ女 and モテ男 for further research, if you're interested.